# excessive printing,process with results

Tags: c, sorting, dictionary

I would like to know a way if I can stop printing the process as the output result. I am coding to sort the strings, and it has excessive printing. Normally, it would only print the end result (what I want), but my code has printed both the process and the results. Is there a way to stop it? 
Below is an example of my problem.

[image]

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define max 9999
#define row 10
#define column 8
#define WORDS 20
char arr[WORDS][1000];
char temp[100];
char str[max], str1[max];
char *s1, *st1;
int e, i, j;
int sort();
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/Users/yiyin/source/repos/project1/project1/tax.txt", "r");


    for (e = 0; e < WORDS; e++)
    {
        fgets(str, max, fp);
        w = strchr(str, ';');
        *w = 0;
        fflush(stdin);
        strcpy(str1, w + 1);


        s1 = strtok(str1, ";");
        do
        {


            st7 = strstr(s1, "s__");

            if (st7 != NULL)
            {
                strcpy(arr[0], st7+3);
                arr[i][0] = 0;

                    sort();
                    for (i = 0; i < WORDS; ++i)
                    {
                        fflush(stdout);
                        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
                    }

            }//if


        } while (s1 = strtok(NULL, ";"));
    }//for
        getchar(); getchar(); getchar(); getchar();
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;

}//main
int sort()
{

        for (i = 0; i <WORDS; ++i)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < WORDS; ++j)
            {
                if (strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) > 0)
                {
                    strcpy(temp, arr[i]);
                    strcpy(arr[i], arr[j]);
                    strcpy(arr[j], temp);
                    break;
                }
            }//for j          
        }//for i
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Start with some error checking. The loop iterates 20 times but there is not that much input according to the screen shot.

Comment: By the way, per the C standard, it is undefined behavior to use `fflush(stdin);`  Just delete that line.

Comment: `w = strchr(str, ';'); *w = 0;` seems to be doing what you use `strtok` for a bit later on.

Comment: Haven't you asked this question yesterday?

Comment: Hi @WeatherVane, the number of times to loop can vary,in my case,i can also put it 3 times,the screenshot shows the problem which as you can see,the output is showing the process of getting the final result.

For the strtok,i am actually just separating the words by scanning for ; and then select the data by looking for s__ using strchr.

Comment: Hi @EugeneSh. yes,i found out that my question is unclear and am not showing most of my codes,so this post is to ask again since i still cannot solve the issue.Hopefully you can help too!

Comment: I would comment that often it helps to make a comment for each sub-section of your code to explain what it is doing, not only to you, but to anyone else (instructor) reading your code.  Reading your native spoken language is often much easier than deciphering C code.  Each string command should probably have a sentence in comments talking about what it is trying to accomplish.  Also, this would be a great time to learn how to use your debugger in single step mode.

Comment: Also, please post something that compiles - right now "w" is undefined as is st7

Comment: Lol - just got bit by a Zombie post.  My bad...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - happens, it could still use an answer -- up for it?

Comment: It does, but all this would do is fix a poorly constructed string tokenizer.  The sample code on how to use `strtok()` already does almost exactly what is needed.  Beyond that, I never did find out all the conditions he was looking for.

Comment: Hi Guys,@MichaelDorgan, @David C. Rankin ,I have managed to solve this issue :) This problem is closed.Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.